# Memory vs Database difference in a variable value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pdf attachment boolean flag set in my application and my database shows it to be set `true`. But when my debugger loads and I inspect the variable it is showing `false` always.

This is the `sql` generated when I fetch the flag.

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `spree_products`.* FROM `spree_products` INNER JOIN `spree_variants` ON `spree_products`.`id` = `spree_variants`.`product_id` INNER JOIN `spree_line_items` ON `spree_variants`.`id` = `spree_line_items`.`variant_id` WHERE `spree_products`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_variants`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_line_items`.`order_id` = 1070722790  ORDER BY spree_line_items.created_at ASC LIMIT 1  [["order_id", 1070722790]]
```

This is what I used for the above result:

```
products.first.attached_pdf
```

This always result in `false`. I don't know if it is bringing the data from memory cache or what but this is being quite nuisance for me right now. Why are the memory and database values different? Any help would be great!

Comment: You probably need to add some code to make this more answerable.

Comment: Can you be more specific what part of application code should I post?

Comment: My database is showing changes but at application level the boolean value isn't updating.

Comment: Do you have a method called `attached_pdf` in your product model? What is the output of `SELECT  attached_pdf FROM spree_products where order_id = 1070722790` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query results are taken from the database query cache (as evident from the `CACHE` debug message) and not from the db. If `products` is an association of some other record, then you may need to [force a real query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching) of the data from the db:

```
products(true).first.attached_pdf
```